# El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada Visual Studio ¿Como puedo solucionarlo?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc

Me encontré con un problema al intentar crear un modelo en un repositorio remoto de GitHub, el mensaje de error dice lo siguiente: El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.
Elimine y volví a clonar el repositorio y el problema persiste.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @DeybiTaboraPaz, bienvenid@ a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Estara mal el archivo de la solucion en el repo? esta buscando una ruta que no existe (que es obvio). Ahora, como arreglarlo, seguro que la solucion es para el VS que estas usando?

Comment: @gbianchi el problema solo me pasa el intentar crear un modelo, puedo crear controladores y otros elementos, recién estoy usando la version 2019 de visual studio y nunca me entre problemas similares en anteriores versiones. El proyecto es una Aplicación web ASP.NET (Web api) y tengo la extensión instalada.

Comment: Y la carpeta existe y tiene permisos?

Comment: @gbianchi Si, estoy en una cuenta local de windows, no he probado ejecutar VS como administrador y intentar crear el modelo, pero no creo que pueda ser eso por que el usuario es administrador.

Comment: La carpeta existe?

Comment: @gbianchi si, es la carpeta que crea por defecto VS para los proyectos

Comment: Entonces no se que decirte. el error es que no esta esa carpeta. probaste reiniciar?

Comment: que pasa si en lugar de crear un modelo creas un class ? basicamente un model es una .cs simple, te deja? usa la opcion de "Add new item"

Comment: @gbianchi al parecer es el error, pero es muy raro por que solo pasa con la carpeta de modelos, VS ya lo reinicie y no creo que tenga que reiniciar la pc. Cuando logre resolver el problema te comentare que es lo que pasaba por si te llegase a pasar.

Comment: @LeandroTuttini No me deja agregar nada en la carpeta de modelos, probé con una interfaz y tampoco la crea, también hice lo que dijiste y tampoco me funciona.

Comment: puedes validar que la carpeta esta creada fisicamente ?  sino usa el windows explorer y creala

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Elimine la carpeta y volví a crearla y al parecer eso resolvió el problema

Comment: @Deybi Encontraste alguna solución. Tengo el mismo error.